# How can I map and return first and last element in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having problem with login return first element and last element:

Here is my array of object:

```
0:
pointAmountMax: 99999
pointAmountMin: 1075
rateCode: ['INAINOW']
roomPoolCode: "ZZAO"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
pointAmountMax: 99999
pointAmountMin: 850
rateCode: ['INAINOJ']
roomPoolCode: "TOGA"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 2
```

How can I map through the array and return the `pointAmountMin` smaller number first?

So in this case I want to achieve something like this in my front end

`return <p>850 - 1075</p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the required output first you will need to sort the array of object in ascending order related to the property pointAmountMin.

```
let arrayOfObj = [
    {
        pointAmountMax: 99999,
        pointAmountMin: 1075,
        rateCode: ['INAINOW'],
        roomPoolCode: "ZZAO",
    },
    {
        pointAmountMax: 99999,
        pointAmountMin: 850,
        rateCode: ['INAINOJ'],
        roomPoolCode: "TOGA",
    }
];

arrayOfObj.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.pointAmountMin - b.pointAmountMin
})
console.log(arrayOfObj)
```

Then collect only pointAmountMin values in an array.

```
const filteredResult = arrayOfObj.map(() => {
  return pointAmountMin
})
```

You have list of all pointAmountMin property values in ascending order (minimum first)
Now you can show it on UI in your required format

```
<p>filteredResult.join(' - ')</p>
```

Comment: What if I have 3 objects in an array, how can I just return first one and last one ?

Comment: Ok so want to show the output like <p> minimum value of pointAmountMin - mamimum value of pointAmountMin</p>?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: Then you can try this way <p>filteredResult[0] + '-' + filteredResult[filteredResult.length-1]</p>

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort()` and then return the desired HTML

```js
function App(){
  const myArray = [
    {
        pointAmountMax: 99999,
        pointAmountMin: 1075,
        somethingElse: null,
    },
    {
        pointAmountMax: 99999,
        pointAmountMin: 650,
        somethingElse: null,
    },
    {
        pointAmountMax: 99999,
        pointAmountMin: 975,
        somethingElse: null,
    }
  ]
  const getRange = (data) => {
    let sorted = data.sort((a,b) => a.pointAmountMin - b.pointAmountMin)
    return [
      <p key={Math.random()}>
        {sorted[0].pointAmountMin} - {sorted.pop().pointAmountMin}
      </p>
    ]
  }
  return <span>{getRange(myArray)}</span>;
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```